# Battery check in background every n seconds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, batterylevel

I need to run a battery check every 5 to 10 minutes, and if the battery level is lower than some percentage, I need to send a push notification. This check needs to be run even if the app is running in the background.

Is it possible for me to run this kind of check? Can I set a timer in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`? Or is there another approach I should use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policy

Comment: A "push notification", by definition, is "pushed" to the phone from an external source. Do you mean a local notification?

Comment: The question appears to be regarding whether it is possible, which is is only secondarily about policy. The first point is whether it's even possible.